# How can i maximize an iFrame with jQuery when clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Can any one tell me how can I Maximize a iFrame when the Div which has iFrame is clicked?? Say for example i have 3 div which has 3 different iFrame on a single page now if anyone clicks on the 1st div I want to maximize that Div to the whole page of browser showing the content of that div. Also I will display a close option on the top which when clicked will close the fullscreen and will return back to the original. Can i do this with jQuery?? or any other javascript library??

Please help me.

Thanks
Pranay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div.iframewrapper").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("maximized");
});
```

---

```
div.maximized { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; }
div.maximized iframe { width:100%; height:100%; border:0 none; }
```

You may also need to set the `z-index` if you got other positioned content on the page.

***Working demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/6SvsX/2

Comment: +1, but it might be nice to have the div shrink back down, so change `addClass` to `toggleClass`

Comment: @fudgey The shrinking is done by clicking on a close button as the OP said.

Comment: @Parry Here: http://jsfiddle.net/6SvsX/ I placed a button which maximizes the DIV.

Comment: thanks it is working now how can i get back I mean minimizing this thing??